# jquery datatable How to remove dropdown filter select values from header while export to excel pdf

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the custom filter select boxes on my dataTables, and trying to implement the export buttons. however, I'm getting  from the select showing up as a heading on the export. 
i want remove dropdown filter select values from header while export to excel pdf or print here is my code i am also attach screenshot of output 
The code I'm using to generate the select filter is:

[Attached screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z982o.png)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#invoicetable').DataTable( {
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
        { extend: 'print', filename: 'Pay Summary',title: 'Pay Summary',footer: true },
        { extend: 'excelHtml5', filename: 'Pay Summary',title: 'Pay Summary',footer: true },
        { extend: 'pdfHtml5', filename: 'Pay Summary', title: 'Pay Summary', footer: true },
    ],
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns([0,2]).every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                } );
            },

            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var totapi = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };
        pageTotal = totapi
            .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

            saltot = totapi
            .column( 5, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

            dectot = totapi
            .column( 6, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

            salpay = totapi
            .column( 7, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( totapi.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
        $( totapi.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(saltot);
        $( totapi.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(dectot);
        $( totapi.column( 7 ).footer() ).html(salpay);
    }

        } );

    } );
```

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we'd be able to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

you can use,

```
exportOptions: { 
            format: {
                header: function ( data, column, row )
                    {
                        return data.substring(data.indexOf("value")+9,data.indexOf("</option"));
                    }
             }
        },
```

Its working for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (all columns except the first column of the table have dropdowns):

My column header text is wrapped within an `<a>` html tag. Eg:  `<a>Column 1</a>`

Then in my dataTables buttons :

```
exportOptions: {
                columns: ":visible",
                format: {
                    header: function (data, column, row) {
                        if (column > 0) {
                            return $(data).prev('a').text();
                        }
                        else
                            return data;

                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my solution i used footer also for my Datatables to solve this problem.
Hide header : it will hide dropdowns also and push footer to first row of your table

```
    buttons: [
        { 
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            header: false, 
            text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel">indir</i>',
            className: 'btn-primary',
            titleAttr: 'Export to Excel',
            columns: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            //hide dropdowns in header
            customizeData: function (exData) {

                var rowNodes = table.rows().nodes();
                var newData = []
                //hide header and bring footer to first row
                exData.body.push(exData.footer)

                debugger
                for (var i = (exData.body.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {

                    if ($(rowNodes[i]).css("display") == "none") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    newData[newData.length] = exData.body[i];
                    debugger
                }
                // the loop reverses order so put it back
                exData.body = newData; 
            }  
        } 
    ],
```